# Absolute positioning in Firefox

Tags: css

I've built this webpage at http://s394436795.websitehome.co.uk/careforall/ and in Chrome & Safari it looks ok, but in Firefox it's broken.

The CSS and HTML is pretty straightforward, I've set most of the DIVs with a absolute position but is this not the best way of doing things? I assumed so...

For example, the HTML for the 'Elderly Care' section is this:

```
<div id="elderlycare">
<h2>Elderly Care</h2>
<p class="elderlycare1">In the many years Aggie has worked as a care worker, she has seen first hand that elderly people prefer the familiar surroundings of their own home and frequently it is a companion that is needed rather than a care company that only supply the basics.</p>
<p class="elderlycare2">Aggie has dedicated her time to a number of clients over the years and prides herself on getting to know them individually. By building friendly and close relationships, she allows you to get that essential break knowing your family is safe and happy in their own home.<br /><br />Aggie is patient, easy to talk to and benefits from being a qualified carer. Not only can she offer company for your relatives, she is able to help professionally with personal hygiene and</p>
<p class="elderlycare3">oversee dietary and nutritional needs. She is also able to provide transportation, be it to or from a train station, an appointment or just a trip to the local shop.<br /><br />A comprehensive meeting with Aggie will be essential before booking in order for her to meet your relative and assess their needs. Please contact her for details.</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#elderlycare h2 {
font-family: 'BebasRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 28px;
color: #515f7f;
font-weight: normal;
}
#elderlycare {
width: 460px;
position: relative;
top: 75px;
left: 320px;
padding: 55px 0 0 0;
margin: 0;
}
.elderlycare1{
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #515f7f;
margin: 0 150px 0 0;
}
.elderlycare2{
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #515f7f;
margin: 35px 0 0 130px;
}
.elderlycare3{
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #515f7f;
margin: 25px 150px 0 0;
}
```

What can be done to ensure all the DIVs can be positioned absolutely in the right place across all browsers. It's quite an awkward design to work with if I'm honest but hope you can help me figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused what you're talking about. I don't see anything that says `position: absolute`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to achieve, but you face some major obstacles. The same font specification won't render identically on different browsers, so you'll always have discrepancies if you micro-manage placement to this extent. Your approach is also giving away one of the most powerful attributes of CSS; the ability to flow content automatically. With that in mind, I can see only disadvantages to having the images and horizontal dividers as part of your page background.

I'd approach this design by floating the images with appropriate padding and letting the text flow around them. The horizontal dividers can be easily positioned between each section.  The result will look much the same - but not 100% identical - in all browsers. Did you try this approach and find it wasn't adequate? Is so, what was the problem with it?

Comment: +1 Madness lies down the path you have taken. You do not have final control over font-size or for that matter, even the font displayed. That is rightly left in the control of the user. There is no way to assure the text will line up with that image.